# Groups in regex python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Below is a piece of code I have been working on and not getting the desired result. I would like to only use groups to split 
elements into group 1 and group 2. For the last two elements I would like to only match `0567` and not `567` for group 2. I get the desired result for `'+1 234 567'` but not for `'0567'` or `'567'`. Please help with this.

```
regex_str = "^(?:\+1)?\s?([123456789]\d{2})\s?([123456789]\d{2})"
PATTERN = re.compile(regex_str)
num = ['+1 234 567','0567', '567']
for i in num:
    m = PATTERN.match(i)
    if m != None:
        print (i," and ",m.group(1),m.group(2))
    else:
        print (i, " has no match")
```

output:

```
+1 234 567  and  234 567
0789  has no match
789  has no match
```

Comment: I've added an answer, but I'm not certain I understand your desired output. Can you edit the question to show what you expect?

Comment: Also, format the outputs in a code bock.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `?` after group 1 to make it optional.

```
regex_str = "^(?:\+1)?\s?([123456789]\d{2})?\s?([123456789]\d{2})"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion using ? works to make group 1 optional. In addition, I had to use ?(1) to make sure group 1 has a correct match before proceeding to group 2 that gave me the answer I desired. Thanks for the help.